# gdb create a Stream

Tags: c++, gdb

i have a program, which get the information from the stream and use cin to read and later convert the input.

This is the calling of the program:

```
cat file1 | ./converter
```

in C++ it is this line

```
while ( ! cin.eof( ) )
```

which reads from the stream.

Is it possible to simulate the pipeline in gdb? 
Because i can not debug the source without it.

Comment: First of all, you should rewrite your program to _not_ do `while (!eof)`. The `eof` flag will not be set until you try to read and it fails, meaning you will have an iteration where the read fails but you probably still continue as if nothing happened. Instead do `while (read_operation)` (like for example `while (std::getline(std::cin, input))`).

Comment: Thx for your comment, i know that .eof() is critical.
But it isn't allowed to change parts of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), like the section on [program input/output](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.html#Input_002fOutput), you will see that you can use normal redirection for the `run` command:

```
(gdb) run < file1
```

This will run your program with `stdin` redirected from `file1`.